# Upload a document to S3 via MS Office Add In

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

We are trying to create a JS MS Office add in that will let users save a document to an S3 bucket, however I am not seeing any way to do that.  Has anyone had any success getting this to wrok?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Amazon SDK for JavaScript to interact with an Amazon S3 bucket. See [Uploading Photos to Amazon S3 from a Browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html) for more information. Don't forget to configure CORS correctly as described in the article mentioned.